# Paging and Bookmarking

Tags: usability, guidelines

Lets say I have blog and I keep on adding Posts.
So on day 1 it will show 5 posts on page 1 and someone bookmarks it.
Next day I add 10 more post and someone opens the bookmark.
They see completely different result.

This happens on all the sites.
Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Most people familiar with blogs will know to navigate to the page of a particular post before bookmarking it.

Comment: What if my blog doesnt have a post page.Its just listing of posts

Comment: Then you are doing your readers a dis-service.

Comment: See also: [Paging: 1 to 42 or 42 back to 1](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/6165/17023) ++ [Why are paginations starting with page 1?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/64664/17023)

Answer (score 1):

If you only show a summary of each post on the first page:

- if they bookmark a post, then it must have been 'opened' with a unique url
- if they want the latest posts, then they can bookmark the summary page
- it's much easier for someone to scan through posts

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty usual convention for blogs. This is also a perfect example of an ***edge case.***

In this particular example it is only ever going to be an issue once you've first launched the site and it has <10 posts published. Once you've reached the maximum for the summary posts page, the 'problem' will never be an issue again.

You shouldn't worry about it. As @Marjan said, most people will bookmark the actual post, those that don't will be few, and of those the only ones who will have this problem will be those that visit your site in the early days when you have <10 posts.

To be quite honest, it is unlikely that a brand new blog with less <10 posts will have the visitor numbers for this issue to arise; *edge case*

Good luck with your new blog and content creation.

Comment: The convention for blogs is that page 1 always shows the newest posts. So on active blogs, all pages will have completely different content after *n* new posts.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, blogs show the newest posts on page 1. So after adding some new posts, there is not a single stable pagination URL anymore, i.e., the URL of the page with the oldest posts changes again and again.

As you mentioned, this is a problem for users bookmarking pagination URLs, but [also for search engine users](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58750/17633), which might land on unrelated pages.

The solution for this problem: use **"reverse" pagination**, as known from, well, log books, diaries etc. (on paper).

You start writing on page 1. Everything written there stays there. The newest entries are on the last page.

For users, the navigation doesn’t have to change, just the URL. So when they are on the front page, clicking at "previous page" will show recent posts, but the URL is not `/page-1` but, e.g., `/page-27`.

Problem with this approach: The first (newest) "previous page" might not contain the full amount (e.g., 10) of posts, temporarily. This *might* confuse some people. (With the typical pagination, this problem exists on the last (oldest) page.)